# Ubuntu doesn't load after adding NVME M2 SSD

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, mount, nvme

Please help with the following:

I have a machine for ML purposes, with both Windows and Ubuntu installed on NVMe M2 disk.

After adding a second NVMe M2 disk Ubuntu won't load after showing Ubuntu logo 3 dots appear.

I thought the problem might be with the new disk being recognized first and therefore changing the pointers to the disks accordingly. When I changed the disks between the motherboard slots, system was  booted into emergency mode with the following message:

> */dev/nvme1n1p3: clean... ... you are in emergency mode...*

- Motherboard is Raider 299x MSI.
- Disks are Samsung 970 PRO/970 EVO Plus M2 disks.
- Also Dedicated GPU is connected.

After disconnecting the new disk the system works normally.

`blkid` output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="e238b9fa-8274-4dcf-87e6-a455c6f191fb" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="6A6C-CFCD" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="5c911710-0bb7-48e9-8aa4-02ab78db0861"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTUUID="9c9f4f64-aef6-4ea2-828b-3887a4e636ef"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="44b8c721-6ed8-49c6-bcfc-02074505f2d7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="86a35a80-e00e-420d-abd3-5fc23ce4a3e8"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="da6eb14f-00eb-4934-853f3-9909cf209711"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="EE8C573D8C57000F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID=""37814981-76fa-4b3a-8b9b-5506ffa1db03"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Elements" UUID="C2A62B4BA62B3EF3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Elements" PARTUUID="a9d83980-2a57-4b92-83b4-82d91ab81054"
```

in fstab:

/ is mounted on nvme0n1p3 UUID

sda and sdb partitions mounted for installed windows with ntfs (irrelevant)

EDIT 2:

After connecting both NVMes and booting into emergency mode I can see that the new disk is being recongnized as nvme0 which I think is causing the problem.

What can I do to fix the disks order?

Comment: What's on the new nvme? Since you redacted important info from `sudo blkid` I can't tell if there's a UUID problem. Have you checked for nvme firmware updates?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? And then are drive gpt partitioned? Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. My Samsung had a ISO that I could use as I do not have Windows to use Samsung Magician for updates.  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @heynnema I haven't checked for NVMe updated because I lose access to the machine after connecting the new NVMe, except when switching the slots.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions, or update `sudo blkid`.

Comment: @heynnema the new NVMe is empty, I edited the post with a screenshot from blkid, though, without the new disk connected.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where a copy/paste would work much better. Please edit your question, delete the older blkid info, and the new screenshot, redo the `sudo blkid`, copy/paste, then select the pasted text and hit the {} icon to format it. Thanks!

Comment: If you reconnect the newer nvme, can you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and then use `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table on the new nvme?

Comment: @heynnema I edited out the image and added the blkid output, I can try to use gparted but could you please explain the reason? shouldn't a new connected disk be recognized automatically?

Comment: Yes, normally a new nvme should work out of the box. Booting to a Ubuntu Live, if you can while the new nvme is connected, will hopefully allow you to init the drive using `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the advice, I’m trying to think what change would it make if I format it. By the way, how does Ubuntu set the order of the disks, I think while the new disk is connected, the old one is being recognized later and therefore the Ubuntu won’t boot (by the way it gets to an Ubuntu logo but doesn’t continue after that)

Comment: Be careful, and fully understand which nvme is which, or you could init the wrong one... better yet... disconnect the bootable nvme, and just leave the bad one connected. Then try booting to the Ubuntu Live and use `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema after connecting both disks I was able to enter in emergency mode and I see the new disk as nvme0, which in my opinion causing the problem. What do you suggest now as we see the disk numbers are changed?

Comment: The disk numbers have changed due to the physical SATA connection priority. Did you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Follow my previous comment, just to be safe.